# Issues with elements that have same By locator on multiple pages

Tags: c#, selenium

I have 5 pages (A, B, C, D, E). A, B, C and D each contain a button with Id 'Next' which will load the next page. Now, the problem is that sometimes (not always), the 'Next' button is not clicked on each page.

My code is supposed to do the following: we launch the browser and navigate to page A by URL. Then, we perform some logic on the page and then we click the 'Next' button. We arrive at page B and perform some logic on the page and click the 'Next' button. We arrive at page C, and immediately click the 'Next' button without doing anything else. On page D, we perform some logic and click the 'Next' button. (and so on...)

Now, the problem is that on page C, the 'Next' button is not always clicked, but it does not throw an error for FindElement. So it tries to perform the logic on page D and the web driver crashes because it's still on page C. How can I fix this problem? Notice that I do use a dynamic webdriverWait for the element to be present on the page, but this makes so difference because the same the locator it always the same (ID = 'Next'). Also, notice I don't return my PageObjects - I'm not sure whether this is absolutely required.

Any thoughts?

Here is my code:

```
   public class Page
    {      
        public Page()
        {
            PageFactory.InitElements(SeleniumTests.driver, this);
        }       
    }

public static class SeleniumTests
    {
        public static IWebDriver driver { get; set; }
    }

 class Page_1 : Page
    {       
        [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "Next")]
        public void Continue()
        {
            btnNext.SafeClick();
        }
    }

class Page_2 : Page
        {       
            [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "Next")]
            public void Continue()
            {
                btnNext.SafeClick();
            }
        }

class Page_3 : Page
        {       
            [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "Next")]
            public void Continue()
            {
                btnNext.SafeClick();
            }
        }
  class Page_4 : Page
            {       
                [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "Next")]
                public void Continue()
                {
                    btnNext.SafeClick();
                }
            }
  class Page_5 : Page
            {       
                [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "Next")]
                public void Continue()
                {
                    btnNext.SafeClick();
                }
            }

   public static class SeleniumExtensionMethod
    { 
        public static WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(SeleniumTests.driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15));
        public static void SafeClick(this IWebElement webElement, Double seconds = 15)
            {
                try
                {
                    wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(webElement)).Click();
                }
                catch (System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException);
                }
            }
    }
```

And finally:

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Page_1 pageA = new Page_1();
        pageA.PerformSomeLogic();
        pageA.Continue();

        Page_2 pageB = new Page_2();
        pageB.PerformSomeLogic();
        pageB.Continue();

        Page_3 pageC = new Page_3();
        // Don't do anything here, just continue.
        pageC.Continue();


        Page_4 pageD = new Page_4();
        pageD.PerformSomeLogic();// -----> here is crashes, as the previous line 'pageC.Continue()' was not really executed, it seems as though the button was clicked 2 times on page B
        pageD.Continue() ;          


        Page_5 pageE = new Page_5();
        pageD.PerformSomeLogic();
        pageE.Continue();   
}
```

Edit: what I want, ideally is to do some kind of dynamic wait which actually would work in this case. I can also use Thread.Sleep(); and this solve my problem but it's a code smell and I want to avoid it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options:

1. make sure the page is loaded and you are on that page
   You can add a `wait.Until()` for a unique element of the page.
2. get the selector for the button based on the parent page
   Since you have `Continue()` in each page object you could use a css selector to identify the button based on the parent page or based on a unique section from the page that does not exists in the other ones, else what is the point on having the same method with the same selector in every page. You can find this easily by using FireBug. Simply navigate to the page, right click the element, click Inspect Element with FireBug, then right click the element and click 'Copy CSS Path'.

For example:
Lets say you have a `div` with `id='pageC'`.
You could use a css selector like `#pageC #Next`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. It's a really simply answer but this helped us a lot. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Your code is overly complex for the task you are attempting to complete.

First get your `IWebDriver`:

```
IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

You should be using an implicit wait in this scenario, lets start with our timeout set to 15 seconds. This will ensure that `driver.FindElements()` calls will search for 15 seconds before timing out. If the element is found before the 15 seconds is up, it will stop the wait at that moment.

```
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15));
```

Since your next button has the same `id` on each of the pages, we can use `By.Id("Next")` to find the next button on each page.

```
driver.FindElement(By.Id("Next"));
```

Putting it all together:

```
IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15));
for(int page = 1; page < 5; page++) //Iterate through all pages, click next when applicable
{
    driver.FindElement(By.Id("Next"));
}
```

or

```
IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15));
if(driver.FindElement(By.Id("Next")).Enabled) //Ensure button is clickable before proceeding
{
    driver.FindElement(By.Id("Next"));
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. But we want to omit any kind of implicit wait as this will also slow down any other calls to FindElement().

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that your script is going fast enough that it is clicking the Next button a second time on Page 2 before Page 3 gets a chance to load. One way around this is to wait for the Next button to be stale. The basic logic would be

```
1. Click the Next button
2. Wait for the Next button to be stale
```

The code might look something like

```
public void Continue()
{
    btnNext.SafeClick();
    btnNext.WaitForStale();
}
```

where `.WaitForStale()` is just

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.stalenessOf(btnNext));
```

Also, unless you've really simplified your Page Objects, there doesn't seem to be a reason to have Page_1 through Page_5. If they all have the same functionality, they should be in a single page and you would just reinstantiate the page each time you move to the next page, e.g.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Page_1 pageA = new Page_1();
    pageA.PerformSomeLogic();
    pageA.Continue();

    pageB = new Page_1(); <-- this can be Page_1() or better yet, renamed to ContentPage or something that better represents the type of page rather than the page number.
    pageB.PerformSomeLogic();
    pageB.Continue();
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. My code is more complex and I used different class names to present the question here on stackoverflow. Basically, the solution was simple, just implement a verification to check that the next page is loaded before clicking the 'Next' button. In fact, we are going to do this and also we will simply rename the IDs of the buttons so this issue can't happen anyway. :)